# Is it "rows by columns" or "columns by rows"?

Tags: terminology

I've got a data table like:

```
ID  Low Color    Med Color     High Color
 1        234          123            324
 2          4          432           3423
```

The rows are widgets, the columns are color levels. Would you call this table "widgets by color level" or "color levels by widget"?

Comment: Look at the Ripley citation at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41306/why-are-probability-distributions-denoted-with-a-tilde

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"That depends."  Rows are usually considered observations, and columns are variables.  So I would say **widgets by color level** in your context.  But it really depends on which are your [dependent and independent variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_and_independent_variables) (or how you're interpreting the data).

Answer (score 6):

Of course you can view this table either way by transposing it.  Conventionally, in a database rows represent objects and columns contain their attributes, whence this presentation would typically be viewed as a list of widgets, not a list of color levels.

Answer (score 5):

for a table like that, I say it the same way I'd say "n by k" for a matrix with n rows and k columns (i.e. rows first).

Answer (score 4):

Typically, we talk about a r(ow) X (c)olumn matrix, from Linear Algebra.  So, a matrix with 2 rows and 3 columns is a 2 X 3 matrix.  By that logic, I'd call your data frame a "Widgets by Color" table.