# Why are probability distributions denoted with a tilde?

Tags: probability, distributions, notation

What is the meaning of the tilde when specifying probability distributions? For example:

$$Z \sim \mbox{Normal}(0,1).$$

Comment: Have a look at point 4 of [this entry](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tilde.html) from Wolfram MathWorld.

Comment: @Procrastinator: you should go ahead and submit this as an answer. I don't think it will get any better.

Comment: In statistics it is used over variable to show the median~X

Comment: It's an oddity (to me) that there is nothing like a standard notation for median, but the fact that a tilde over a symbol may be sometimes be used for median, or indeed for other summaries of a variable, has nothing whatsoever to do with this notation.

Comment: Tilde ∼ means "is sampled from this distribution"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The ~ (tilde) used in that way means "is distributed as". Why? To ask why doesn't make much sense to me, its just a convention. To cite Brian Ripley:

> Mathematical conventions are just that, conventions. They differ by
>   field of mathematics. Don't ask us why matrix rows are numbered down
>   but graphs are numbered up the y axis, nor why x comes before y but
>   row before column. But the matrix layout has always seemed illogical
>   to me.    -- Brian D. Ripley (answering a question why print(x) and
>   image(x) are layouted differently)
>         R-help (August 2004)

Comment: I'll wait and see if someone comes up with an idea about the history or the "why" and if not i'll accept this one

Answer (score 14):

I can't comment on the history, but I believe it might be the following.  The ~ symbol is commonly used in mathematics to denote an equivalence relation.  In the context of probability theory it is used to denote equivalance in (marginal) distribution.  So when we say,

Z ~ N(0,1),

what we mean is that the random variable Z has the same marginal distribution as the random variable N(0,1).  (The latter being a standard normal random variable, by definition.)  This interpretation requires that you interpret the right-hand-side of the equation as referring to a random variable, not a distribution function.  Under this interpretation, the ~ sign means "has the same distribution as".  Since this is reflexive, symmetric and transitive, it is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Equivalence relation *on what set*?  There is no such thing as a "set of all random variables."

Comment: One probably could have "something like" equivalence relations in the contect of categories, that is, on proper classes.