# Why is $\rho$ used for both the population correlation and the Spearman estimate?

Tags: correlation, stochastic-processes, notation, pearson-r, spearman-rho

I am wondering why the notation "rho", written $\rho$, is used to denote the [population correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence), whereas it's also used to denote the [Spearman correlation estimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient). In [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) it's used to represent the Pearson population correlation.

Is there some sense behind this? Is $\rho$ analogous to the "volatility" of a stochastic process, which is an ambiguous term without a strict definition that can be estimated in different ways?

Comment: I don't think there is a special rule for using the same symbol to represent different things. The same could be said about $X$, it is used to represent either a random variable or a Banach space; $\sigma$ is used for representing the standard deviation and a scale parameter ... Some symbols become popular for representing certain concepts. $\rho$ is typically used for different types of correlation. In this case, both concepts are well-defined/demarcated but coincidentally they were denoted with the same symbol.

Comment: @Procrastinator Thank you. Perhaps you should submit an answer?

Comment: I would add that a subscript is often added to denote Spearman correlation as $\rho_S$.

Comment: See my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41306/why-are-probability-distributions-denoted-with-a-tilde/41332#41332

Comment: If we didn't use symbols to designate multiple things (depending on context), we would shortly run out of symbols altogether.

Answer (score 2):

As the others already noted in the comments, mathematical notation in statistics can be all over the place. Consider the following uses of the notation $\lambda$:

- The [factor loadings](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/seminars/rcfa/) in structural equation models
- The [smoothing parameter](https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2015/07/30/gam/) in generalized additive models
- One of the distributional "inputs" for the [Poisson distribution](https://www.scribbr.com/frequently-asked-questions/what-does-lambda-mean/)
- The [Wilk's lambda](https://www.statisticshowto.com/wilks-lambda/) used in MANOVA (though usually noted as $\Lambda$ instead of $\lambda$).

As such, the notation $\rho$ as an indicator of a population correlation and as the Spearman coefficient is somewhat tangentially related and are likely why they have both been used in this way. Notation is often buried in the context of the mathematical problem, and if we are lucky it is consistent across writings.

Comment: There arent enough symbols in use for every concept to have its own!