# How to interpret this notation with a tilde?

Tags: conditional-probability, notation, distributions

The following convention is sometimes encountered in the text (here **example** from HMM statement, $\{X_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is a Markov process):

$$X_n \mid (X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}) \sim f(x_n \mid x_{n-1})$$

It is clear, what it means for the "plain" case ([Why are probability distributions denoted with a tilde?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41306/why-are-probability-distributions-denoted-with-a-tilde)), but what about the meaning of full formal notation when we have the conditional part $\mid\ (X_{n-1} = x_{n-1})$?

Comment: It's describing the conditional distribution (rather than the unconditional distribution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be translated to English as:

The distribution of $X_n$, conditional on $X_{n-1}$ taking the value $x_{n-1}$, is described by the probability density function $f(x_n \mid x_{n-1})$.

Comment: Thanks, could you please also write it in another notation, as I believe the original is just an abbreviation, or is the $X|Y$ the most used one? (If my guess is right, it should be something with p())

Comment: $X\mid Y$ is standard. For example, $P( X=x \mid Y =y)$, often written $P(X\mid Y)$ is the probability that $X$ takes the value $x$ given $Y$ takes the value $y$. $E[X \mid Y=y]$ is the expectation of $X$ conditional on $Y$ takes value $y$.  $X \mid Y $ in general refers to $X$ conditional on $Y$.

Comment: Ok. Those others are of course very familiar, but the version without any "functors" around was confusing.

Comment: @RomanSusi No worries. There's a lot of notation around the use of probability. We've all had our confused "uhhh, so what is this?" moments!

Comment: Even better would be to translate it to English as: "The distribution of $X_n$, conditional on $X_{n-1}$ taking the value $x_{n-1}$, is described by the probability density function $f(\ \mid x_{n-1})$."