# Why is the letter $n$ traditionally used to denote sample size?

Tags: notation, history

Question basically in title. I am just curious if anyone has any historical references that point to the earliest usages of this notation.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41306/why-are-probability-distributions-denoted-with-a-tilde/41332#41332

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Sure, but that answer pertains to matrices and matrices have a history dating back 2000 years. Modern statistical notation was largely developed in the 20th century.

Comment: Well, but that was not the point. The point was that conventions are conventions, they are what they are, good or bad, and asking Why does' nt make much sense. Asking about history is ifferent.

Comment: There are some close votes. I do not understand why this is opinion-based, it is asking for historical references, which is clear and on-topic

Comment: I'm tempted to guess n is short for number, but not sure. I do know that it's not upper case to distinguish it from population size (N).

Comment: It is not opinion-based but it can considered off topic because it doesn't really pertain to issues in statistics, data mining or machine learning. Also although answers to this could be known if there is an historical reason, it seems that we are only guessing.

Comment: It is not in David's lists of first occurrences of statistical terms (either 1995 one or 1998). However since American Statistician was willing to publish those lists this question does seem to be to be on topic.

Comment: The notation comes directly from mathematics -- collections of things in mathematics are frequently counted $1,2,...,n$. So, for example, you can see Pearson in 1900 (in ordinary use of mathematical notation) referring to a collection of deviations from expected as $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ (in a goodness of fit situation). From that standard use of mathematical notation to labelling original observations in a similar fashion, and so having the sample size be $n$ is an obvious step. I'd say you would have to go back to the first use of $n$ in mathematics to refer to an unspecified number of objects

Comment: ... so for example, you have Cayley in 1843 referring to $n$ dimensions, and this is the same sense in which Pearson was using $n$ in 1900.